# Insert value to custom field using getForm (setFieldAttribute)

Tags: jform, model, jmodel

I would like to add some data to a form field I declared in my forms.xml. This form field is a custom form field which is declared like this:

```
<fields name = "userdata">
    <fieldset name = "personal-data">
        <field name = "test" 
           type = "myfield" 
           size = "40" 
           country = "DE"
           label = "COM_BESTIA_FIELDS_TEST_LABEL"
           description = "COM_BESTIA_FIELDS_TEST_DESC" 
           required = "true" 
           filter = "safehtml" />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Now I would like to use

```
$form = $this->loadForm('com_bestia.item', 'item', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
$form->setFieldAttribute('test', 'country', 'US');
```

to add a specific value to the `country` attribute.

If I do that this way, there are no changes - it still shows `DE`.

Comment: Have you tried $form->setValue() instead

Comment: Hm, still no success :-( No error-message or something like that.

Comment: I tried to do it with `$form->setValue('test', 'country', 'US');`

Answer (score 3):

Mea culpa,

I had to add the name of the  group:

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('test', 'country', 'US', 'personal');
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, please award the green tick to your answer so that this page is deemed to be resolved.